# Replacing Part of Text Using Sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I have the following text file

```
Eif2ak1.aSep07
Eif2ak1.aSep07
LOC100042862.aSep07-unspliced
NADH5_C.0.aSep07-unspliced
LOC100042862.aSep07-unspliced
NADH5_C.0.aSep07-unspliced
```

What I want to do is to remove all the text starting from period (.) to the end.
But why this command doesn't do it?

```
sed 's/\.*//g' myfile.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a period there. You want:

```
s/\..*$//g
```

Comment: You've escaped the period to make it a literal.  To match the rest of the line, you'll need another matching pattern, like '.*' or better yet '.*$'.  That makes your expression look like Clint's

Answer (score 1):

you can use `awk` or `cut`, since dots are your delimters.

```
$4 awk -F"." '{print $1}' file
Eif2ak1
Eif2ak1
LOC100042862
NADH5_C
LOC100042862
NADH5_C

$ cut -d"." -f1 file
Eif2ak1
Eif2ak1
LOC100042862
NADH5_C
LOC100042862
NADH5_C
```

easier than using regular expression.